# Methods in a class -Python

Tags: python

In python how to  know the methods of a class

`Ex: import datetime is a module which  has a date class in it..
And print datetime.date.today()`

will yield todays date.

How to know all the methods of a class

`help(datetime) and dir(datetime)` are the only way..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First solution

Following [Björn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565557/methods-in-a-class-python/5565592#5565592) and the [Dive-into-Python chapter](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html) using `callable(getattr(classname))`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> c=datetime.datetime
>>> methodList = [method for method in dir(c) if callable(getattr(c, method))]
>>> methodList
['__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', 
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__radd__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
 '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', 
 '__subclasshook__', 'astimezone', 'combine', 'ctime', 'date', 'dst', 
 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 
 'now', 'replace', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'time', 'timetuple', 'timetz', 
 'today', 'toordinal', 'tzname', 'utcfromtimestamp', 'utcnow', 'utcoffset',
 'utctimetuple', 'weekday']
```

#### Second solution - after reading [Guandalino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573034/guandalino)'s comment

```
>>> methodList = [item for item in dir(c) 
                  if type(getattr(c, item))==type(getattr(c,'__new__'))]
>>> methodList
['__new__', '__subclasshook__', 'combine', 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 
 'now', 'strptime', 'today', 'utcfromtimestamp', 'utcnow']
```

This technique relies on the fact that the `__new__` attribute is always a method (It can be overridden, but every other keyword can).

Comment: Python methods are not the only callable objects, f.e. classes are callable too. For this reason I'm not sure the callable trick fits the OP question (asking for _methods_ of a class).

Answer (score 2):

[The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods, functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects.](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pprint, inspect
>>> predicate = inspect.ismethoddescriptor
>>> methods = inspect.getmembers(datetime, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
>>> descriptors = inspect.getmembers(datetime, predicate=inspect.ismethoddescriptor)
>>> methods.extend(descriptors)
>>> methods = [method[0] for method in methods]
>>> pprint.pprint(methods)
['__add__',
'__delattr__',
'__eq__',
'__format__',
'__ge__',
'__getattribute__',
'__gt__',
'__hash__',
'__init__',
'__le__',
'__lt__',
'__ne__',
'__radd__',
'__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__'
'__repr__',
'__rsub__',
'__setattr__',
'__sizeof__',
'__str__',
'__sub__',
'astimezone',
'ctime',
'date',
'dst',
'isocalendar',
'isoformat',
'isoweekday',
'replace',
'strftime',
'time',
'timetuple',
'timetz',
'toordinal',
'tzname',
'utcoffset',
'utctimetuple',
'weekday']
```

Comment: +1 `dir` is fine for interactive use, but always use `inspect` for programmatic uses.

Answer (score 1):

In python this is called `Introspection`, you can see some examples of it [here](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class A(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.field=1
            class B(object):
                pass
            self.myclass=B
            self.myinstance=B()
        def mymethod(x):
            print x

>>> a=A()
>>> import inspect
>>> methods=[name for name in dir(a) if inspect.ismethod(getattr(a,name))]
>>> methods
['__init__', 'mymethod']
>>>
```

Comment: This does not filter the methods.

Comment: @AdamMatan JFTR, meanwhile it does.